# Audio producer threads with OSX AudioComponent consumer thread and callback in C

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, core-audio

This question is not about a plugin, it's about a standalone application program design and is connected with few questions I've asked before.

I have to write a multi-threaded audio synthesizing function, whose amount of data crunching **by far exceeds** what can get accomodated on the **CoreAudio** render thread: several thousands of independent amplitude and phase interpolating sample-accurate sine-wave oscillators in real time. This requires more CPU power than any single processor core can bear, with all the optimizations available.

I'm doing my best to learn it, but it seems a wall, not a curve. The consumer thread may be a simple **CA** real-time priority render callback accepting *AudioBufferList  iodata*, etc…
…but what should be the producer thread(s)? If choosing another AudioComponent, it does no better than having it all on the output thread - it only gets more complicated and introduces additional latency.

If putting **n** parallel AudioComponents into a **graph** which feeds a ring buffer, which feeds the consumer thread, how can one guarantee it'll not end up on the same thread, stay in sync and sample-accurate?

If writing **n** traditional POSIX threads with joining outputs, how to achieve the CoreAudio pull-model would coexist with such a push model in real time?

Is there any such freely available example code ? Is there a reference, a textbook or a tutorial in writing such a code? I haven't found any publicly available information. It makes me kind of wonder that such question hadn't been asked before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be to have a separate thread (or threads) generating your  LPCM audio in real-time and writing it to a suitably sized ring buffer. The core audio thread would read from this ring buffer.

If the reader (core audio thread) requests more audio than is available then you get a drop out ([buffer underrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun)), because the reader cannot wait. This indicates that you need a larger buffer, or that your audio generation algorithm is not realtime and needs optimisation.

If the writer tries to write to the ring buffer when it is full, the oldest audio is overwritten and you have another glitch, this time via overrun. In this case your audio generation code is running too fast and needs to learn how to wait. Here it would be convenient to add write waitability, via a condition variable.

I know of two cool ringbuffer implementations that use virtual memory tricks to efficiently implement the modular memory access:

- Mike Ash's [MAMirroredQueue](https://github.com/mikeash/MAMirroredQueue)
- Michael Tyson's [TPCircularBuffer](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer)

If you're looking for something more portable, there's [CBuffer](https://github.com/willemt/cbuffer) for unix-like systems and [Magic Ring Buffer](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/the-magic-ring-buffer/) for Windows.

However! You don't have to use tricky MMU ring buffers, you can use a plain old portable C version if you like.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very reasonable direction. I've studied M. Tyson's TPCircularBuffer. Still, I'm a bit confused on how to write a (non-CoreAudio) thread that would constantly run and fill a circular buffer with either computed samples or zeroes, and would communicate to the render thread, without blocking anything else. I'd prefer not to be too OSX specific. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added some notes about blocking and non-osx vm ring buffers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but would you please be so kind to let know where have you added the notes, please?

Comment: Follow-up: TPCircularBuffer seems to pose no major implementation obstacle, the only issue would be how to spawn and control one or more producer threads (outside the main thread). Learning wait by means of a dispatch_semaphore_wait( ) call seems a very good concept, IMHO.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for as far as TPCircularBuffer is concerned! Do you perhaps know where I can find an example (and what API would one need - as UNIX as practical) for running and controlling (non-CoreAudio) data producer threads, which would write to the circular buffer without blocking the main tread? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use a pthread condition variable for that part. Google should give you many examples. Or dispatch_semaphore as you mentioned.

Comment: Following some research I found a working partial answer to the question, using `dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            [self producer: on];
        });` call to fire-up the producer thread and _dispatch_semaphore_ for syncing. I'll gladly post the code here if it can be of any help to anyone. However, this concept cannot facilitate segmentation of the producer thread into subthreads which can then run in parallel on multiple CPU cores. I'd highly appreciate a hint for moving in that direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you ask it as a new question?

Comment: Thanks, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241278/audio-samples-producer-multiple-threads-osx

Comment: As you've implemented the advice given in this answer in your new question, surely this question is answered?

Comment: Thanks for your good advice and your kind interest. I'm afraid the question is only partly answered. I wish I could have understood more about implementing pthread condition variable here, as you have advised. It would have made the code more portable, which is my objective.

Comment: You want to eliminate gcd from your other question?

Comment: GCD is here for me a quick way to get things work at all. I'd indeed prefer to learn getting rid of it in favor of portability, if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fine with POSIX programming as long as it does not go for tampering with **CoreAudio** real time pull-model render threads. Should the render callback set the `pthread_mutex_lock (&lock)` at the beginning of its cycle and `pthread_cond_signal (&cond);` and `pthread_mutex_unlock (&lock)` at the end of the render cycle, while the producer thread(s) set the `pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &lock);` during _cond_ being false?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your useful and guiding reply and comments. IMHO I'm still quite far in terms ofunderstanding what should replace the **top-level dispatch call**: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        if((multithreading)||(NF))
            producerSum(on);
        else
            producer(on);
    });`
 (as quoted in question's follow-up), since we have to fire the producer from the main thread. So in fact we have **three threads** : main thread, producer thread with its subthreads, and render thread, which all have to communicate with one another.

Comment: This is no longer about audio but rather thread synchronisation. You need to break your question up into to something like "how to rewrite this gcd code as posix" and "how to structure multiple producer/consumer". Good luck

Comment: Thanks very much for notifying about possibly slipping off-topic. Thanks for the question restructuring idea & suggestion as well. I'll do that ASAP.

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers to your questions, possibly because they're over-specific to your exact case. A refactor may help.

Comment: Thanks very much, on the contrary I have marked having accepted your answer as _**useful**_. I've also marked all the comments which I've found useful for helping move in the right direction. Is this OK? –

Comment: Now, having had my original question elaborated into three follow-ups, having completed enough individual research to combine partial answers and results to the point of having had almost 90% of the question answered, I can accept your answer as "having been most helpful in finding my solution", although it's been a long way to go. Thanks!