# Audio samples producer multiple threads OSX

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, multiprocessing, core-audio

This question is a follow-up to a former question ([Audio producer threads with OSX AudioComponent consumer thread and callback in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355364/audio-producer-threads-with-osx-audiocomponent-consumer-thread-and-callback-in-c/29357926?noredirect=1#comment56209364_29357926)), including a test example, which works and behaves as expected but does not quite answer the question. I have **substantially rephrased** the question, and re-coded the example, so that it ***only*** contains plain-C code. (I've found out that few Objective-C portions of code in the former example only caused confusion and distracted the reader from what's essential in the question.)

In order to take advantage of multiple processor cores as well as to make the **CoreAudio** pull-model render thread as lightweight as possible, the LPCM samples' producer routine clearly has to "sit" on a different thread, outside the real-lime-priority render thread/callback. It must feed the samples to a circular buffer (**TPCircularBuffer** in this example), from which the system would schedule data pull-out in quants of inNumberFrames.

The Grand Central Dispatch API offers a simple solution, which I've deduced upon some individual research (including trial-and-error coding). This solution is elegant, since it doesn't block anything nor conflict between push and pull models. Yet the GCD, which is supposed to take care of "sub-threading" does not *by far* meet the specific parallelization requirements for the work threads of the producer code, so I had to explicitely spawn a number of POSIX threads, depending on the number of logical cores available. Although results are already remarkable in terms of speeding-up the computation I still feel a bit unconfortable mixing the POSIX and GCD. In particular it goes for the variable **wait_interval**, and computing it properly, not by predicting how many PCM samples may the render thread require for the next cycle.

Here's the shortened and simplified (pseudo)code for my **test program**, in plain-C.

Controller declaration:

```c
#include "TPCircularBuffer.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
TPCircularBuffer            buffer;
AudioComponentInstance      toneUnit;
Float64                     sampleRate;
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;   
Float32*                     f;     //array of updated frequencies
Float32*                     a;     //array of updated amps
Float32*                     prevf; //array of prev. frequencies
Float32*                     preva; //array of prev. amps
Float32*                     val;
    int*                    arg;
    int*                    previous_arg;
UInt32                      frames;
int                         state;
Boolean                     midif; //wip
} MyAudioController;

MyAudioController gen;    
dispatch_semaphore_t mSemaphore;
Boolean multithreading, NF;

typedef struct data{
    int tid;
    int cpuCount;
}data;
```

Controller management:

```
void setup (void){
    // Initialize circular buffer
    TPCircularBufferInit(&(self->buffer), kBufferLength);
    // Create the semaphore
    mSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    // Setup audio
    createToneUnit(&gen);  
}

void dealloc (void) {
    // Release buffer resources
    TPCircularBufferCleanup(&buffer);
    // Clean up semaphore
    dispatch_release(mSemaphore);
    // dispose of audio
    if(gen.toneUnit){
        AudioOutputUnitStop(gen.toneUnit);
        AudioUnitUninitialize(gen.toneUnit);
        AudioComponentInstanceDispose(gen.toneUnit);
    }
}
```

Dispatcher call (launching producer queue from the main thread):

```
void dproducer (Boolean on, Boolean multithreading, Boolean NF)
{
if (on == true)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        if((multithreading)||(NF))
            producerSum(on);
        else
            producer(on);
    });
}
return;
}
```

Threadable producer routine:

```
void producerSum(Boolean on)
{
int rc;
int num = getCPUnum();
pthread_t threads[num];
data thread_args[num];
void* resulT;
static Float32 frames  [FR_MAX];
Float32 wait_interval;
int     bytesToCopy;
Float32 floatmax;

while(on){
    wait_interval = FACT*(gen.frames)/(gen.sampleRate);
    Float32 damp = 1./(Float32)(gen.frames);
    bytesToCopy = gen.frames*sizeof(Float32);
    memset(frames,  0, FR_MAX*sizeof(Float32));
    availableBytes = 0;
    fbuffW  = (Float32**)calloc(num + 1, sizeof(Float32*));
    for (int i=0; i<num; ++i)
    {
        fbuffW[i] = (Float32*)calloc(gen.frames, sizeof(Float32));
        thread_args[i].tid = i; 
        thread_args[i].cpuCount = num;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, producerTN, (void *) &thread_args[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<num; ++i)  rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &resulT);

    for(UInt32 samp = 0; samp < gen.frames; samp++)
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            frames[samp] += fbuffW[i][samp];

    //code for managing producer state and GUI updates
    { ... }

    float *head = TPCircularBufferHead(&(gen.buffer), &availableBytes);
    memcpy(head,(const void*)frames,MIN(bytesToCopy, availableBytes));//copies frames to head
    TPCircularBufferProduce(&(gen.buffer),MIN(bytesToCopy,availableBytes));

dispatch_semaphore_wait(mSemaphore, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, wait_interval * NSEC_PER_SEC));
if(gen.state == stopped){gen.state = idle; on = false;}

for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        free(fbuffW[i]);
free(fbuffW);
}
return;
}
```

A single producer thread may look somewhat like this:

```
void *producerT  (void *TN)
{
Float32 samples[FR_MAX];
data threadData;
threadData = *((data *)TN);
int tid  = threadData.tid;
int step = threadData.cpuCount;
int *ret = calloc(1,sizeof(int));

do_something(tid, step, &samples);

{ … }
return (void*)ret;
}
```

Here is the render callback (CoreAudio real-time consumer thread):

```
static OSStatus audioRenderCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {    

MyAudioController *THIS = (MyAudioController *)inRefCon;

// An event happens in the render thread- signal whoever is waiting
if (THIS->state == active) dispatch_semaphore_signal(mSemaphore);

// Mono audio rendering: we only need one target buffer
const int channel = 0;
Float32* targetBuffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;
memset(targetBuffer,0,inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));

// Pull samples from circular buffer
int32_t availableBytes;    
Float32 *buffer = TPCircularBufferTail(&THIS->buffer, &availableBytes);

//copy circularBuffer content to target buffer
int bytesToCopy = ioData->mBuffers[channel].mDataByteSize;
memcpy(targetBuffer, buffer, MIN(bytesToCopy, availableBytes));
{ … };

TPCircularBufferConsume(&THIS->buffer, availableBytes);    
THIS->frames = inNumberFrames;
return noErr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, aside few Objective-C methods, which are basically wrap-ups, all the relevant portions of code are written in **plain-C**, since C POSIX and CoreAudio APIs are C APIs. So sorry, this **is** C. Please, pardon my commenting.

Comment: Simply: does it compiler with a C compiler? No. So it is **not** C. Otherwise it would also be C++, Java, Rust, etc. Just similar or partly same syntax does not make two languages the same. And yes, I know, ObjC is a true superset of C, but not vice-versa!

Comment: Code cleaned up to contain **only** plain-C

Comment: Your mixing of gcd and posix is nothing to worry about, `dispatch_semaphore` isn't going to do anything strange in the presence of `pthreads`. The required number of samples in the render thread should be fixed, or at least very predictable depending on your hardware sample rate. Not sure what the actual problem here is.

Comment: The required number of samples in the render thread is hardware dependent indeed (variable _inNumberFrames_). The problem is: (1) how to compute and implement the _wait_interval_ variable in this model, or (2) how to possibly completely get rid of GCD in favor of making the code more portable (POSIX/BSD). How could one implement pthread conditional variable in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Grand Central Dispatch already takes care of dispatching operations to multiple processor cores and threads.  In typical real-time audio rendering or processing, one never needs to wait on a signal or semaphore, as the circular buffer consumption rate is very predictable, and drifts extremely slowly over time.  The AVAudioSession API (if available) and Audio Unit API and callback allow you to set and determine the callback buffer size, and thus the maximum rate at which the circular buffer can change.  Thus you can dispatch all render operations on a timer, render the exact number needed per timer period, and let the buffer size and state compensate for any jitter in thread dispatch time.

In extremely long running audio renders, you might want to measure the drift between timer operations and real-time audio consumption (sample rate), and tweak the number of samples rendered or the timer offset.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I don't and cannot deal with AVAudioSession API, since this code has nothing to do with iOS, which is hopefully visible from the post's title and sample format, nor do I intend making a OSX/iOS cross-platform code. I'd also prefer programmatically segmenting the sample generating code myself. I don't intend questioning reliability of GCD which is great IMHO. I'd simply prefer keeping the sample generating routine more UNIX plain-C  source compatible (which a moderator didn't let me tag), if it is possible. This means I'll probably have to sacrifice the GCD-approach altogether.

Comment: Use of the AudioSession API is optional.  A similar timing scheme works on OS X using GCD or NSTimers.  These timer callbacks can wrap plain C sample generators on both OS X and iOS (I use the same C audio synth code for both).

Comment: Thanks for your effort and good advice, yet, what I'm writing is not even a NSApplicaton. This code is a test. I'd like to keep as much UNIX portability as I can. I'm using CA render callback on OSX only because it is native, debuggable and does not lure into writing a NSApp. I'd prefer to keep the sample generating thread(s) "Cocoa-free". It's so also because of the nature of the sonification data. Is there a simple example code of how can POSIX producer threads "work in harmony and in real time" with a CA consumer thread? I'd be more than grateful if someone would point me in that direction.

Comment: @user3078414 this is a good answer, not sure why you didn't accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer - it's a good answer, I don't doubt it. Following few weeks research, I found out that unfortunately **GCD can't meet these specific parallelization requirements by far** -they are too specific. So I had to code explicit parallelizing. Therefore I substantially rephrased the question and rewrote the example code. Please be so kind to read new information in the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason separate near realtime producer threads work is because the fixed audio sample rate allows you to know almost exactly how many samples to produce each timer tick.  Thus you don't need to calculate the wait time, as it can be a constant (the timer tuck interval) set up at audio initialization, based on the minimum audio buffer size requested.